# Flutter textformfileds validation

Tags: flutter

In my code I am using validator to validate in texformfields and it is working fine, and now what I want is if user doesn't type anything and just presses enter button I want the data which is in **hinttext** to be sent to server and if hint text doesn't any contain data and if user presses button then I want validation texts.

```
 Textfields( 
 hintText: data.data.firstName == null ? 'First Name' : data.data.firstName,
 validator: validateNames,
 onChanged: (String value) {
 firstName = value; },
 onSaved: (input) => firstName = input,
 autofocus: true,
 prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
 ),
```

**This is my button**

```
 BlocBuilder<BasicInfoCubit, BasicInfoState>(
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          return Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            child: CustomButton(
                              horizontal: kDefaultSpacing,
                              width: size.width / 2.5,
                              title: 'Continue ',
                              isDisabled: false,
                              loading: state.maybeWhen(
                                orElse: () => false,
                                loading: () => true,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                final isValid =
                                    _formKey.currentState?.validate();
                                if (!isValid!) {
                                  return;
                                } else {
                                  await context
                                      .read<BasicInfoCubit>()
                                      .basicInfo(
                                        firstName: firstName == null
                                            ? data.data.firstName.toString()
                                            : firstName.toString(),
                                   
                                      );
                                  Future.delayed(
                                    const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                  );
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable holding the hint and use the same hint's value while submitting.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const SignUpApp());

class SignUpApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const SignUpScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SignUpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SignUpScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: const Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 400,
          child: Card(
            child: SignUpForm(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SignUpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpForm({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpForm> createState() => _SignUpFormState();
}

class _SignUpFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static const String _firstNameHint = 'First name';
  late TextEditingController _firstNameTextController;
  late TextEditingController _lastNameTextController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _firstNameTextController = TextEditingController();
    _lastNameTextController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstNameTextController.dispose();
    _lastNameTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _submit() {
    if (_formKey.currentState != null && _formKey.currentState!.validate()) {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _firstNameTextController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: _firstNameHint,
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  if (_firstNameHint.isNotEmpty) {
                    _firstNameTextController.text = _firstNameHint;
                    return null;
                  }
                  return 'First name is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _lastNameTextController,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Last name is required';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _submit();
            },
            child: const Text('Sign up'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also create a Custom TextFormField which will do all of the above.